# Blocking LAN client WAN access with a exception rule

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to block a specific client access to the WAN with this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.X.X -o $WAN_INTERFACE -j DROP
```

I however need a exception to allow outbound connections to a specific IP, so I need an ACCEPT rule before it in the right chain.

What is the best way to create this exception and block everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `-I` on iptables then you need to specify the rule number, what you can do is:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s ${limitedClient} -o ${WAN_INTERFACE} -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s ${limitedClient} -d ${limitedClientAccess} -o ${WAN_INTERFACE} -j ACCEPT
```

This way you will first insert a rule to deny this IP access to Internet, then you will put in first position a rule allowing specific access to this IP to somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you needed to specify a rule number when using `-I`

Comment: You're welcome :). With `-A` you just insert the rule at the end of rulesets, but once you have your rules applied, instead of delete all them and add all you can manage to insert at certain places or delete just one `-D chain rulesetnumber`

Comment: Good to know thanks. In terms of additional exceptions would it be possible to provide the functionality above but allowing a specific incoming port to expose a service only?

Comment: Normally it should be possible. But would help being more precise (or use an example)

Comment: Say if I had a service running on port 8080 on the LAN that I wanted to have that exposed to be externally accessible. With the current rule setup the drop rule would block any port forward from working. I was wondering if there is a similar exception rule like allowing outgoing connections to specific IP addresses.

Comment: On that case you should have a rule at the beginning allowing traffic from the outside interface to that ip:port; but also a DNAT to translate from outside to inside. Taken from [here](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html) `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d ${outsideAddress} --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination ${insideAddress}`

Comment: Glad to help! :)